Configure EAP TLS between two directly connected Windows10/11 computers
I'va been told that there is EAP TLS configuration between two directly connected computers running windows 10/11.
Windows 10 < utp cable > windows 11/10

So far i can not figure it out how to achive this kind of configuration. As far as I know there must be checked  "Enable IEEE 802.1x auth" button in auth property of given interface.
Does anyone knows if it is possible and if so how to configure EAP TLS between both computers ?

As far as I know  it's not possible to configure 802.1X this way. Windows only has the 'client' ("supplicant") side of 802.1X and EAP – but not the 'server' ("authenticator") side.
(The latter is usually found only in Ethernet switches (and many Wi-Fi access points under the "WPA-Enterprise" name). Often it also requires a separate RADIUS server to handle the actual EAP handshake (i.e. the switch merely forwards EAP from 802.1X to UDP), though some switches do have built-in EAP-TLS server-side support.
Linux can technically act as a wired 802.1X "authenticator" using hostapd for experiments, but there it's not very useful unless manually integrated with some kind of traffic filtering. It is fully functional with Wi-Fi however.)
The same EAP is also used in other places besides 802.1X, such as IPsec – it can be used for client authentication in IKEv2 VPNs. Even there, though, as far as I know Windows client editions can't accept it, nor would it make much sense IMO (IKEv2 already has built-in certificate auth).

Thanks for info grawity.
